# How does CONVERT (DATETIME, FLOAT) work?

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

So I have a floating point **41617.063633** and I want to know how its made from a DATETIME .
I have worked out the left side of the floating point (number of days since *12/30/1899*).

But I'm stuck on the right side. I assume its a count of seconds or something, but I can't get the right side (*063633*) no matter what I try from the time part of the DATETIME string.

Below is the SQL to get the left side:

```
DECLARE @targetDate DATETIME = '12/9/2013 12:31:37';
DECLARE @floor DATETIME = '12/30/1899 0:00:00'
DECLARE @gmt TIME = '11:00:00';
DECLARE @left VARCHAR (8) = DATEDIFF(DAY, @floor , CONVERT (DATE, @targetDate));
DECLARE @right VARCHAR (8) = '0';
SELECT @left + '.' + @right AS [FloatingTime]
```

I know I can use the next bit of SQL to work it out for me:

```
SELECT CONVERT (DATETIME, 41617.063633)
```

But since I have come so close to figuring this out, could someone get me over the line?

Do you know how to calculate the right side of the floating point (*the time part of the string*)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct about the meaning of the whole number part (the part to the left of the decimal). The fractional part (the part to the right of the decimal) indicates a portion of a 24-hour period.

```
Decimal value    Time Value    Calculation 
=============    ==========    ===========
0.00094444444    12:01:00 AM   1.0 / 24 / 60 (1 day/24 hours/60 minutes per hour)
0.01041666666    12:15:00 AM   1.0 / 24 / 60 * 15
0.02083333333    12:30:00 AM   1.0 / 24 / 60 * 30
0.04166666666    01:00:00 AM   1.0 / 24
```

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on what type of datetime.  There is currently 6 different version in SQL Server 2012.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff848733.aspx

As for date time, the value should be interpreted as two 32-bit integers.

The number of days since 1/1/1900 and the time since midnight.  It is accurate to increments of .000, .003, or .007 seconds or 3 ms.  I would check this out but it might be the count of 3 ms since midnight.

Again, you need to really know what generated the date to accurately decode the hex / number.

Answer (score 0):

As @ken-white says, the decimal is a fraction of a 24-hour day.  So to get the time, multiply the decimal part of the float by 24 to get the time:

```
.063633 * 24 = 1.527 = 1:31.6 am
```

Answer (score 0):

It's multiplied against the number of minutes in a day:
1440 minutes in a day.

```
1140 * .063633 = 91.63152
```

Which is 1 hour, 31 minutes, 37 seconds.

Your example, converted to a datetime:
[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/873d5/7)

Which comes out as:

```
December, 11 2013 01:31:37+0000
```

Comment: But how do you tell AM from PM?

Comment: @user1909158 1 hour after midnight could only be 1AM. 13 hours after midnight would be 1PM.