# TSQL: How to format time: '0.729166667' like Excel does: '5:30:00 pm'

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I have a table in T-SQL that has 2 columns with the following formats:

```
Column_name Type    Computed    Length  Prec    Scale   Nullable    TrimTrailingBlanks  FixedLenNullInSource    Collation
LocCd       varchar no              -1                  yes         no                  yes                     SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
TimeField   float   no               8    53    NULL    yes         (n/a)               (n/a)                   NULL
```

The values of the two columns are:

```
LocCd  Timefield
A      0.729166666666667
B      0.791666666666667
C      0.770833333333333
D      0.791666666666667
```

The `timefield` is a valid time field, and excel reads it in just fine when formatted using 'time'. However, I can't get SQL to recognize it. Here's what Excel looks like when I copy the column and format it as 'time':

```
loc_cd  Raw time: SQL   Formatted time: Excel
A       0.729166667     5:30:00 PM
B       0.791666667     7:00:00 PM
C       0.770833333     6:30:00 PM
D       0.791666667     7:00:00 PM
```

How do I do this in T-SQL? The code I've been messing with is below:

```sql
select loccd,
       timefield
--  Ive been messing with every format I can find, below.  
--     DATEADD(S, CONVERT(int,LEFT(scheduled, 10)), '1970-01-01')
from tablename;
```

Comment: `cast(0.729166666666667 as datetime)`

Comment: Who decided to store time as a float? You might want to reconsider that, since there is a `time` data type that is far more appropriate.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does CONVERT (DATETIME, FLOAT) work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20462643/how-does-convert-datetime-float-work)

Comment: *"The `timefield` is a valid time field"* the fact that it is a `float`, and not a `time` means that it by definition *isn't* a valid time **column**.

Comment: Also, I just noticed that `NocID` is defined as a`varchar(MAX)`. If it's an ID why does it need up to **2GB** in size *per* value?

Answer (score 3):

The "time" you have stored appears to be the percentage of the day that has been finished.

There are at least a couple of ways to do that:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(LocCd char(1), Timefield float);

INSERT @t(LocCd, Timefield) VALUES
('A', 0.729166666666667),
('B', 0.791666666666667),
('C', 0.770833333333333),
('D', 0.791666666666667);

SELECT *, CONVERT(time, CONVERT(datetime, Timefield)) 
  FROM @t;

SELECT *, CONVERT(time, DATEADD(MILLISECOND, Timefield * 86400000, 0))
  FROM @t;
```

Both results:

> | LocCd | Timefield | (No column name) |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | A | 0.729166666666667 | 17:30:00 |
> | B | 0.791666666666667 | 19:00:00 |
> | C | 0.770833333333333 | 18:30:00 |
> | D | 0.791666666666667 | 19:00:00 |

- Example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=9b8ee1ad6c6b47cef2ace56ecbd876c9)

However I strongly recommend revisiting the decision to store "time" as a float representing the fraction of the day. When you use the wrong data type, you lose any kind of validation, e.g. what is stopping a user from entering `-542.92434324`? And you force tedious reverse engineering to present the data correctly, like this, which wouldn't be required if you used the right data type from the start. I don't mention storing `time` as `float` specifically, but lots more info at [Bad Habits to Kick : Choosing the wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type).